# Linux: keytool says "Unrecognized command: -exportcert"

Tags: android, linux, facebook, keytool, fingerprint

In documentation of [Facebook API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/#samples) or in [documentation for Android developers](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/android#step_1_acquire_a_sha1_fingerprint) is mentioned that you should use keytool command, e. g.:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -list -v
```

But when you paste it to the terminal you can only see an error:

```
Unrecognized command: -exportcert
Usage:  keytool [COMMAND] [-- COMMAND]...
Manage private keys and public certificates.

Available commands:
  -genkey         Generate a Key Entry, eventually creating a key store.
                    [-alias ALIAS] [-keyalg ALGORITHM] [-keysize KEY_SIZE]
                    [-sigalg ALGORITHM] [-dname NAME] [-keypass PASSWORD]
                    [-validity DAY_COUNT] [-storetype STORE_TYPE]
                    [-keystore URL] [-storepass PASSWORD]
                    [-provider PROVIDER_CLASS_NAME] [-v].
  -import         Add Key Entries and Trusted Certificates.
                    [-alias ALIAS] [-file FILE] [-keypass PASSWORD]
                    [-noprompt] [-trustcacerts] [-storetype STORE_TYPE]
                    [-keystore URL] [-storepass PASSWORD]
                    [-provider PROVIDER_CLASS_NAME] [-v].
  -selfcert       Generate a self-signed Trusted Certificate.
                    [-alias ALIAS] [-sigalg ALGORITHM] [-dname NAME]
                    [-validity DAY_COUNT] [-keypass PASSWORD]
                    [-storetype STORE_TYPE] [-keystore URL]
                    [-storepass PASSWORD] [-provider PROVIDER_CLASS_NAME] [-v].
  -identitydb     NOT IMPLEMENTED YET.  Import JDK1.1 Identity Database.
                    [-file FILE] [-storetype STORE_TYPE] [-keystore URL]
                    [-storepass PASSWORD] [-provider PROVIDER_CLASS_NAME] [-v].
  -certreq        Issue a Certificate Signing Request (CSR).
                    [-alias ALIAS] [-sigalg ALGORITHM] [-file FILE]
                    [-keypass PASSWORD] [-storetype STORE_TYPE] [-keystore URL]
                    [-storepass PASSWORD] [-provider PROVIDER_CLASS_NAME] [-v]
                    [-attributes].
  -export         Export a Certificate from a key store.
                    [-alias ALIAS] [-file FILE] [-storetype STORE_TYPE]
                    [-keystore URL] [-storepass PASSWORD]
                    [-provider PROVIDER_CLASS_NAME] [-rfc] [-v].
  -list           Print one or all Certificates in a key store to STDOUT.
                    [-alias ALIAS] [-storetype STORE_TYPE] [-keystore URL]
                    [-storepass PASSWORD] [-provider PROVIDER_CLASS_NAME] 
                    [-rfc] [-v].
  -printcert      Print a human-readable form of a Certificate in a FILE.
                    [-file FILE] [-v].
  -keyclone       Clone a Key Entry in a key store.
                    [-alias ALIAS] [-dest ALIAS] [-keypass PASSWORD]
                    [-new PASSWORD] [-storetype STORE_TYPE] [-keystore URL]
                    [-storepass PASSWORD] [-provider PROVIDER_CLASS_NAME] [-v].
  -storepasswd    Change the password protecting a key store.
                    [-new PASSWORD] [-storetype STORE_TYPE] [-keystore URL]
                    [-storepass PASSWORD] [-provider PROVIDER_CLASS_NAME] [-v].
  -keypasswd      Change the password protecting a Key Entry in a key store.
                    [-alias ALIAS] [-keypass PASSWORD] [-new PASSWORD]
                    [-storetype STORE_TYPE] [-keystore URL]
                    [-storepass PASSWORD] [-provider PROVIDER_CLASS_NAME] [-v].
  -delete         Delete a Key Entry or a Trusted Certificate from a key store.
                    [-alias ALIAS] [-storetype STORE_TYPE] [-keystore URL]
                    [-storepass PASSWORD] [-provider PROVIDER_CLASS_NAME] [-v].
  -cacert         Import a CA's Trusted Certificate.
                    [-file FILE] [-storetype STORE_TYPE] [-keystore URL]
                    [-storepass PASSWORD] [-provider PROVIDER_CLASS_NAME] [-v].

Standard options:
      -help       print this help, then exit
      -version    print version number, then exit
  -JOPTION        pass argument to the Java runtime

Please report bugs at http://www.gnu.org/software/classpath/bugs.html
```

What is wrong and how can I fix it? I'm running Linux Mint 17.2 Cinnamon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that there are two different tools with the same name "keytool".

One comes with your linux distribution and it is used by default when you write the "keytool" command in your terminal. When you run `man keytool` you can see the description:

```
NAME
       gkeytool - Manage private keys and public certificate
```

But for your purposes it is required to use the keytool which comes with your Java installation – you have to locate to the Java directory, for me it is in `/opt/java/jdk1.8.0_65/bin`. When you are here, just run the same command, but use `./keytool` instead of `keytool` at the beginning of the command, e. g.:

```
./keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -list -v
```